# CS50 pset3 runoff print_winner

Tags: c, cs50

I can't find why it's throwing the error as when I manually input it works fine.
but throws an error when they use their system.
:( print_winner prints name when someone has a majority
print_winner did not print winner of election
:( print_winner returns true when someone has a majority
print_winner did not print winner and then return true

```
int votes_need;

// printf("votes needed: %i\n", votes_need);
for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
{
    if (voter_count % 2 != 0)
    {
        votes_need = ((voter_count + 1 )/ 2);

        if (candidates[i].votes >= votes_need)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("no winner yet!!!\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        votes_need = ((voter_count)/ 2);

        if (candidates[i].votes > votes_need)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("no winner yet!!!\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Hello.  Please share a minimal version of the code so that the community can evaluate the code.  For example, there is evidently a structure definition for each candidate.  It would be helpful to see how that is defined.  Regards.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `else` clauses that `return false;`  *within* the `i` loop. As soon as it finds a candidate with fewer than half the votes, the function is over and returns to the caller. Maybe when you manually input, candidate[0] is always the winner.

Comment: actually you are correct I found the error. When I remove the else statements its working fine. Actually candidate[0] is not always the winner, but it's solved. Thanks for your precious time.